# Laravel passport 7.5.1 - Replicating claims

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-passport

We are having a new error related with laravel/passport: 7.5.1. Today, this library has been working as the last week. But this stops showing this message via Postman:

> Replicating claims as headers is deprecated and will removed from v4.0. Please manually set the header if you need it replicated.

Do someone knows something about this issue?

We don't know how to continue with this...

We're using Laravel 5.7 (we know that...)

Answer (score 9):

We "solved" this temporally downgrading the library lcobucci/jwt from 3.4.0 to 3.3.3.

Comment: how to downgrading the package in laravel

Comment: You can run `composer require lcobucci/jwt`. This will put lcobucci/jwt in your composer.json file. And then you can edit the version there. After updating the version, run `composer update`. You'd then be running on the selected version.

Answer (score 7):

help me in laravel 5.8

set in composer.json

```
"laravel/passport": "^7.5",
"lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.2",
```

and update vendor

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 3):

For me downgrading, lcobucci/jwt worked for me. I was currently using 3.4.* but downgraded it to a constant 3.3.3

to downgrade I run the command

```
composer require lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3
```

And that was it. But my only concern is I am not certain if this is a temporary or a permanent solution to this issue. But at least it will reboot things up if your system failed cause of that error

Comment: Anyone with a more permanent solution can help out as I want to believe that this is a temporary solution. And it's only present in lcobucci/jwt 3.4 and above. I would appreciate